# What are all the Beacon Special Effects?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

In FTL, some beacons have some of the following "environmental/special effects":

1. Asteroid Field

   - periodically an asteroid "attacks" yours and the enemy ships - causing 1 damage
2. Ion Storm

   - half available reactor power (removed randomly if in use)
3. Too Close to the Sun

   - periodically the sun flares causing random fires on yours and the enemy ships
4. Planetary Defence Cannons

   - periodically the planet's weapons fire into space against yours or the enemy ships, maybe both
5. Ion Event

   - random amount of ion damage is applied to several systems on yours and the enemy ships

Not sure of the names for #4 and 5 (both added with Advanced Content).

Does anyone have more specific information about these beacon modifiers (or any I have missed)?

- How often does each happen?
- How much damage does each do (where applicable)?
- Anything else of note?

Comment: I originally read this title as "What are all the Bacon Special Effects?"

Comment: @batophobia special effects of bacon include: excessive salivation, dietary malpractice, and satisfied taste buds

Answer (score 3):

So the full list is

1. Giant star

   - this creates random fires in your and the enemy's ships and, as a secondary effect, will cause hull damage if a system is destroyed
2. Nebula

   - this disrupts the sensors and rebels' speed is halved for the next jump
3. Plasma storms

   - this causes the reactor to run at half efficiency as well as disrupting sensors
4. Asteroid field

   - this causes asteroids to periodically strike your ship and the enemy's ship.  If your ship is running with just 1 shield with an unskilled crewmember at the station, it can take damage just from asteroids as the period between asteroids is random.  Each asteroid does 1 damage.
5. Pulsar

   - New to the advanced edition. This causes 2 or 3 ion damage to a system   (shields if they are up) and 1 ion damage to another system (if shields are down)
6. Anti-ship battery

   - New to the advanced edition. This randomly sends a shield piercing 3 damage shot to your or the enemy ship, hitting a random room and causing a hull breach.  While you will be shot at multiple times, the only one that may hit will give you a warning before doing so.

For more info go [here](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Environmental_Hazards)

Long-range scanner augmentation will give you, in essence, advanced warning about most of these hazards!

Comment: The ASB will often target only one of the two ships.  In particular, it will target your ship when the rebel fleet catches up with you.  (I have also seen an event where it targeted only the enemy ship.)

Comment: @Brilliand I've changed an and to an or

Comment: This answer has some mistakes.  The Giant star will cause damage to your hull even if a system isn't destroyed.  I've had it happen dozens of times when it hit a system-less room. Also, Nebulae do not half the rebels' speed if you are in a nebula system.  In those cases it seems to slow them somewhere between 25% and 33%. Also the asteroids are not completely random.  Some fields strike more quickly than others, although there is some variance within a field. I'm not sure about your pulsar ion damage amounts either.

Comment: doesn't plasma storms happen in nebulas only?

Comment: @vaxquis Yes; that is correct. So you can avoid those nasty effects if you can avoid nebulae beacons.